# Left-align text in math-mode and break equations

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, align

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}



\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\emph{This should be left-aligned and have no eq-number}\\
1&\neq 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+01000000+2\\ %should be broken
1&\neq 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+01000000+2   %should be broken
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve the following

1. The first line should be left-aligned and have no number
2. The second and third line should be broken as they are too long

Is it possible to do so with the `align`-environment?

Comment: Should only the third line be numbered? Have you tried `multline` or a combination `multiline`+`aligned`?

Comment: @campa All lines that contain equations should be numbered

Comment: The first line should be outside the `align`: there's no reason for it to be inside, is there?

Comment: @egreg yes, I would like to have multiple of these constructions within the environment, so I need to keep it inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` for the left aligned text, depending on the required spacing. `\shortintertext` gives tighter spacing.

For breaking the lines, you can place them in `multlined` environments from the [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package. You can specify the width as an optional argument if that is preferred, and also customize other aspects of the environment. See the package documentation for more information.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \shortintertext{\emph{This should be left-aligned and have no eq-number}}
  1 &\neq \begin{multlined}[t][7cm]
      1+2+3+4+5+6\\
      {}+7+8+9+01000000+2
    \end{multlined}\\
  1 &\neq \begin{multlined}[t]
    1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9\\
    {}+01000000+2
  \end{multlined}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output 1]

Alternatively you can use only the `align` environment, and use the `\nonumber` command on lines that shouldn't be numbered, although I personally find the `multlined` approach better. To get the binary operators to the right of `\neq` one can use `\hpantom{\neq{}}` which inserts a space with equal width as `\neq` and the following space.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \intertext{\emph{This should be left-aligned and have no eq-number}}
  1 &\neq 1+2+3+4+5+6 \nonumber\\
    &\hphantom{\neq{}}+7+8+9+01000000+2\\
  1 &\neq 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 \nonumber\\
    &\hphantom{\neq{}}+01000000+2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output 2]

Answer (score 1):

Use `intertext` or `\shortintertext` (the latter from `mathtools`; needless to load `amsmath` in that case):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \intertext{\emph{This should be left-aligned and have no eq-number}}
  1 & \neq 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+01000000+2 \\ %should be broken
  1 & \neq 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+01000000+2 %should be broken
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \shortintertext{\emph{This should be left-aligned and have no eq-number}}
  1 & \neq 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+01000000+2 \\ %should be broken
  1 & \neq 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+01000000+2 %should be broken
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]